# Inno Setup how to force restart in the end

Tags: inno-setup, restart

Does anyone know how to force the user to restart the computer after finishing the installation?
With the AlwaysRestart=yes Setup's directive, all it does is to prompt the user to restart, to choose between now or later, but it does not actually restart automatically or only shows the option to 'restart now'.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That is not possible. This [`is hardcoded`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Main.pas#L3903) and there is no event which would fire to let it change (e.g. by hiding the *No, I will restart the computer later* radio button).

But that is correct. You should never shutdown the system without the user's permission. They may lose data when you would do so.

Comment: I don't want to reboot without user's permission. I just want to show to the user in the finish page that after clicking in finish, setup will restart, like there're in many others setups.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. If you set `AlwaysRestart` to `yes`, two radio buttons appear on the final page where the *Yes, restart the computer now* one is checked, so the user can just press *Finish* button to restart the system. So I don't see any problem here. However, if you are asking how to show a message dialog instead of those radio buttons, even that is not possible to do. Such message box is shown, but only if you run the setup in silent mode.

Comment: I want to only show one radio button, alarming the user that the restart is required.

Comment: Ok, I see. That's the case I described in my answer as *there is no event which would fire to let it change (e.g. by hiding the No, I will restart the computer later radio button).*

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
  [Tasks]
  Name: "RestartPC"; Description: "Restart the Computer"; GroupDescription: "Post Installation Options"; Flags: unchecked;

  [Code]
  function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
  begin
    if IsTaskSelected('RestartPC') then
      Result := False;
  end;

  procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);  
  var
  intResultCode: Integer;
  begin
    if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
      if IsTaskSelected('RestartPC') then
        NeedRestart;
    if CurStep = ssDone then
      begin
        if IsTaskSelected('RestartPC') then
          if SuppressibleMsgBox('A restart was selected, or Setup must restart your computer to complete the installation.' + #13#10 + #13#10 +
            'Would you like to restart now?',
            mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO, IDYES) = IDYES then
              Exec('shutdown.exe', '-r -t 0', '', SW_HIDE,
                ewNoWait, intResultCode);
      end;
  end;
```

Comment: Then you would need to set some sort of *never restart* directive to prevent the installer to ever request restart. The `ssDone` step [`is signalled`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Main.pas#L4049) when the final page is already showing. But even if it wasn't, you would still need to prevent the setup to ever ask for restart since the user may cancel your dialog and when the setup needs a restart, the final page with those radio buttons would appear (so the user would be asked twice for the same).

Comment: @TLama Would need to check, but would it not be possible to use `if IsTaskSelected('RestartPC') then NeedResart := False` at some earlier point in the installation (prior to ssDone) in order to prevent the radio buttons appearing?

Comment: I suppose you mean to return False from the `PrepareToInstall` event. Well, that event is for you to additionally request restart. Inno Setup handles its own restart requests when they are necessary, so this won't stop Inno Setup from asking for restart if needed.

Comment: @TLama I was actually thinking more along the lines of `if CurStep = ssPostInstall` in the same `procedure CurStepChanged`

Comment: Code updated to prevent double-prompt for restart. This seems to work. This could be modified to always force a restart by hiding the Task, removing the unchecked flag and changing the message box to be a non-suppressible MB_OK, simply warning that the computer will restart. @TLama Do you see any problems doing it this way?

Comment: If Inno Setup internally determines that it needs restart (e.g. when copying of a certain file fails), it sets the `NeedsRestart` boolean variable to True. And [`look at the condition`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Install.pas#L2721) in which the `NeedRestart` event is fired (`if not NeedsRestart then <fire the event>`). P.S. that statement should be written as `Result := not IsTaskSelected('RestartPC');` otherwise you would leave the function result undefined (which is not critical, but should not be so).

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. `NeedRestart` would only be set to `False` if the `RestartPC` Task is selected at the end of the install before the Finish screen is displayed, allowing the `MsgBox` to handle the restart instead.

Comment: That's what I see, but the problem is that you have to suppress Inno Setup's own restart request. If Inno Setup e.g. fails to copy a file (with `restartreplace` flag specified), it sets the `NeedsRestart` variable to True and the `NeedRestart` event will not fire. Inno Setup internal restart request has a precedence and there is no way to interrupt nor cancel it later on.

Comment: And you must suppress Inno Setup's own restart request because guess what happens if you show your message box and the user says no. A default radio buttons will show up asking one more time for restart.

Comment: OK, sort of follow, but if it the computer's being restarted, does it actually make any difference whether or not the restart is initiated by the internal request or not? The user can always choose not to restart from the internally triggered request anyway.

Comment: By setting `NeedRestart` to `False` at that point, is that not already suppressing the internal request? Not sure how it could prompt again, given that the message box is only displayed after the Finish page has already been displayed?

Comment: No. If the internal request was planned (the `NeedsRestart == True`), the `NeedRestart` event is not fired at all. And well, I would not find a big problem if you'll be shutting down the computer and the radio buttons appear. Worse I'm finding that you popup a message box asking for the restart and I choose no. Then the final page shows with radio buttons asking again for restart (because of the internal request). That's annoying.

Comment: Ah, I think I see my confusion now. `NeedRestart` is actually a separate function to the `NeedsRestart` variable, the value of which is determined by the internal request? I thought they were one and the same thing. Hmm, there must be a way to do this cleanly. I am trying to make a Task that can be selected to automatically prompt to reboot when finished, but won't do so without user approval. I wonder, is there a way to set the `AlwaysRestart` to `yes` based on a Task selection instead? That would probably do the job.

Comment: The `AlwaysRestart` is not the way to go. The internal request is controlled by the `NeedsRestart` variable (here it [`gets initialized`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Main.pas#L2966) from the `AlwaysRestart` directive). And naturally, once this variable is set to True, there should be nothing that would change it. Hence the `NeedRestart` event is not fired in that case (to prevent cancelling the existing internal request).

Comment: I wonder, could this be done using `AlwaysRestart={code:IsRestartPCSelected}` where `function IsRestartPCSelected` returns `yes` based on `IsTaskSelected('RestartPC')`? Better still, is there a way to query the status of the internal variable `NeedsRestart` from the [Code] section, as I want the restart to take place after `ssDone` finishes running additional tasks.

Comment: Nope. The `AlwaysRestart` directive is used for the only thing, to initialize the `NeedsRestart` variable at setup initialization (see the code I linked in my previous comment). And no, there is no way to change that variable from outside. Inno Setup simply prevents from cancelling its internal restart request.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are talking at slight cross purposes? It sounds like `AlwaysRestart` might work, as if `IsTaskSelected('RestartPC')` sets this as `yes`, it means the internal request to restart i.e. `NeedsRestart` variable is then set to `True`, meaning the `function NeedRestart` is no longer needed as Inno Setup would be prompting for a restart on the Finish page using the radio buttons determined by the internal request? However, it would not allow me to run additional tasks in the `ssDone` section, so rather than changing `NeedsRestart` from [Code] can it's condition simply be read?

Comment: Nope, it is just internal variable that cannot be accessed from script. But wait, you might create a fake final page placed before the real one and exit the setup from that custom page.